# Mysql left Join - sum of two columns is error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables,

**TABLE A** Entry Table

```
| id | user     | task_date  |count|
|----|----------|------------|-----|
| 1  | king     | 2020-08-01 | 100 |
| 2  | king     | 2020-08-02 | 300 |
| 3  | king     | 2020-08-04 | 50  | 
| 4  | king     | 2020-08-03 | 90  |
| 5  | king     | 2020-08-05 | 70  |
| 6  | king     | 2020-08-06 | 20  |
| 7  | king     | 2020-08-07 | 20  |
| 8  | king     | 2020-08-08 | 220 |
| 9  | king     | 2020-08-09 | 30  |
| 10 | king     | 2020-08-04 | 40  |
```

**Table B** Error table

```
| id | user     | dev_date   |error_count|
|----|----------|------------|-----------|
| 25 | king     | 2020-08-01 | 10        |
| 22 | king     | 2020-08-02 | 10        |
| 20 | king     | 2020-08-04 | 20        |
```

**Expected output**

```
| SumOfCount| SumOfError|
|-----------|-----------|
| 940       |40         |
```

I have tried this

```
select
sum(a.count),sum(b.error_count)
from entry_table a
LEFT JOIN  error_table b ON a.user = b.user
where a.user = "king" and a.task_date between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-31' and b.dev_date between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-31'
```

it is showing invalid sum. where am i making mistake?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: got it, sorry ! i will add the create statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many to may relationship between both of the tables due to that  `SumOfCount` will increase by 3 times and `SumOfError` will increase by 10 times because you are first joining then aggregating. But here you have to do reverse first Aggregate then Join

Try in this way

```
select 
a.SumOfCount, b.SumOfError
from (
select user, sum(count) SumOfCount
from entry_table where user='king' and task_date between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-31' 
) a left join 

(
select user, sum(error_count) SumOfError
from error_table where user='king' and dev_date between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-31'
) b on a.user=b.user
```